# How do I step into the server automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use asp API for register domains, but when run my program I get this error:

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the
>   server machine 'www.systemnic.ir' failed. The debugger cannot connect
>   to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does
>   not exist or a firewall may be be preventing communication to the
>   remote computer. Please see help for assistance.

My program runs for Local, Should I put it on my server?

How do I do this?

Comment: is www.systemnic.ir your system hosted on an environment you are in control of?

Comment: yes, This is a website for register domains.

Comment: and this is a service you try to debug?

Comment: I never use from web service and dont have any information about this

Comment: you have to start the service in a debug session , and then run your client as normal then you can debug it

Comment: I do it, but  I met an exception about web services :(

Comment: @Thorarins Do you have any guidance for step into the server automaticly?

Comment: in visual studio , right klick on the service project and chose Debug-> Start new instance ,  then you start debugging on your client / web application

Comment: @Thorarins ,I'm so sorry :(( I do this but I met exception again !!